# 5000rpm vs 5500rpm circular saw

Tags: circular-saw

I’m looking to purchase a circular saw and I’ve narrowed it down to two,
A Ryobi that is 1250w that spins at 5000 rpm and a Bosch saw that is 1400w that spins at 5500rpm,
The question I am asking is does the extra 500 rpm make that much of a difference for the extra cost? And does anybody have experience with these two brands of saw?

Comment: Good Answer by @SaSSafraS1232, but I don't necessarily agree with the conclusion. As a general thing I think it's rare someone will regret getting a tool with more power, but you can most assuredly regret getting something with less! In this case because the power ratings are close-ish I agree that you won't notice in most jobs the saw will be asked to do, but the extra power may then show up in a longer service life — the motor is being stressed less every time it's used. That said, if you aren't likely to be using it a lot most days (few people do) the Ryobi would well be *good enough*.

Comment: @Graphus just out of curiosity what is the main difference between saws that range from £300+, to saws below £100 ?

Comment: @Neamus - That would be a question in its own right, but basically you are looking at the quality of the components, the fit and finish of the tool, and the branding overhead.

Comment: @Neamus I have had great luck with Ryobi tools. All of my cordless tools and 2 string trimmers are Ryobi. I did have one tool almost start of fire (String trimmer) but they replace it no cost. Not even shipping and gave extra battery and charger. Great costumer service, Amazing tools. I recommend them. Bosch I have not used so can't say. And reading the answers below it is true ryobi is not your professional brand. But I did beat my friends DeWalt impact with my Roybi impact in a lag bolt competition.  Both 18v li-ion and everything. All I can say is, I do like Ryobi. And every brand has....

Comment: Strong point and weak point. Meaning brand A will make a much better table saw than brand B. But brand B could make a much better miter saw than brand A.

Comment: Please note that brand recommendation questions are off-topic and often can lead to extended discussion which is not ideal for the Stack Exchange fomat. Closing this question to avoid attracting brand recommendation answers which detract from the primary question, but will gladly reopen if you remove the "And does anybody have experience with these two brands of saw?" For future reference, it is often best to omit brand names when possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requests opinions of specific brands

Comment: @Neamus Unfortunately I can only give a generic answer as it depends on which £300+ saw one might be talking about. Just because something is more costly (even outright pricey) it's actually not any guarantee of innate quality. Not of the entire thing always but down to the level of individual components which they might cheap out on (Festool are an example here, despite their extortionate pricing). What I would *hope* for is better quality of materials and construction, better QC, more power or better power delivery. Combined result being greater reliability and longer service life.

Comment: @rob if you'd like to close the question its fine, ive got all the information i needed for the meantime, regards

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you going to notice the difference between a saw running at 5000 rpm and one running at 5500rpm?  No, probably not.

Are you going to notice 1250 watts vs 1400 watts?  Again, probably not.

What you are going to notice is if the blade is sharp, if the fence is square to the blade, how accurate the bevel adjustment is, etc.  All of these types of things are likely to be better in a Bosch than in a Ryobi.

Answer (score 4):

My experience with Ryobi tools that they are not for the professional or frequent user. I have worked as a technician using Ryobi tools for several years and found the shaft bearings on the drills failed after a couple years, the parts that needed to be made of tough but not hardened steel tended to wear out faster than the guys with Bosch, DeWalt, or most of the higher end brands. I'd get the Bosch because it will wear longer and maintain it's accuracy far longer than the Ryobi. I have since changed all my Ryobi power tools for Ridgid.

Now, to directly answer the question. Aside from the quality and repeatability of cuts is when (and it will happen) you are making a careful set of cuts and you hit the unexpected sap laden knot in the wood. The Ryobi will be more likely to slow and want to get away from you than the stronger Bosch. It may seem strange but the more powerful machines are safer than the lesser ones because they are more likely to continue cutting without the blade wanting to twist or bind. Sudden changes in blade speed can cause a loss of control. Spend the money on quality equipment and you will be safer and have them far longer. Ultimately, this makes the expensive stuff cost less in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer is no. However, you might want to consider other  wider factors:  My experience as a heavyweight diy-er and occasional work with trades makes me avoid ryobi. If I was buying cheap I'd go for erbauer, wickes or even lidl over ryobi. They'll cost you less & will be OK for occasional diy use. If you want better than that, the Bosch will be much better built & has been covered above. Note that Bosch green are the consumer models & blue are trade rated ones. The green are still well-regarded & IMO better than ryobi by some margin.You pays yer money...

Comment: Can you add any comments in relation to the primary question about the value of a faster or more powerful circ saw?

Comment: No please delete my answer. I forgot that, on SE, the letter of the question is all.